# How to optimize your query when you are dealing with large collections in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm dealing with two collections in Mongo DB User and UserHistory. Where User collection contains the static information of a particular user and in the UserHistroy table there can be multiple records for a specific User, related to his/her history. I have the user Id of a user and a set of other fields related values in each collection. I just want to check whether is there any record satisfying those criteria.

**User** 
-userId
-name
-type
-class

**UserHistory** 
-userId
-usage
-balance
-billed_value

I have "userId" = 'XXX', "type" = 'YYY' , "class" = 'ZZZ' from User collection and "balance" = 60 value related to UserHistroy collection.
I want to know there is a relevant user which satisfies all the above. (Optimal manner) => lookups might be somewhat time-consuming since the collections contain a large amount of data.

I'm using Golang to implement this logic.

Comment: Use [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) to speed up your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can add $limit in your $lookup sub query to avoid lookup all documents from `UserHistory`. You can then check the lookup array being empty or not for your further logic.

Here is a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ByXtszIccmW) for your reference.

You can also see that as common performance tuning practice, the $match stages are put at the early stages to make the query as selective as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Could try using the cursor option, get the first filtered set from "User" with query on "userId" = 'XXX', "type" = 'YYY' , "class" = 'ZZZ'
and then using the userid or _id , query on "UserHistory" with  "balance" = 60